# Getchar() skips the first value scanned in while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, char, scanf, getchar

I am trying to select all individual values scanned (cannot use arrays or strings) one at a time. For now, it skips the first value implemented by the user and I do not know why. I would like the loop to stop when getchar reaches "=" which will be at the end of the scanned value.

```
int main () {
char c;
while(scanf("%c", &c) != '=') {
 c=getchar();
 printf("print ");
 putchar(c);

 }
return 0;
}
```

In the terminal, when I input "a=" I only receive the "=" instead of "a". Can someone help?

Comment: check what [`scanf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) returns (it's not the input character)

Comment: Never use `"%c"`.  Always use `" %c"`. (Note the space.)

Comment: In the context of `scanf("%c", &c)`, the only possible return values are 1 and EOF (0 is not among the possibilities).  If there is no character to read, then it will return EOF; otherwise, it will return 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the while loop and the following call of `getchar` do not make a sense.

```
while(scanf("%c", &c) != '=') {
 c=getchar();
 //...
```

For example *The C Standard, 7.21.6.4 The scanf function)

> 3 The scanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input
> failure occurs before the first conversion (if any) has completed.
> Otherwise, the scanf function returns the number of input items
> assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in the
> event of an early matching failure.

And the read character by the call of scanf is not outputted.

You should write

```
char c;
while( scanf(" %c", &c) == 1 && c != '=') {
 printf("print %c", c);
}
```

Pay attention to that this call of scanf

```
scanf( " %c", &c)
```

will skip white space characters. If you want to output any character then you need to remove the blank before the conversion specifier like

```
scanf( "%c", &c)
       ^^^^
```

If you want to use `getchar` then the loop will look like

```
int c;
while( ( c = getchar() ) != EOF && c != '=') {
 printf("print %c", c);
}
```

In this case as you see the variable `c` must be declared as having the type `int`.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf()` function returns the number of fields that were successfully converted and assigned.

You can read more here: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=functions-scanf-read-data

In your case, it will return 1 if c is scanned and assigned successfully, else 0.

The above documentation is platform-specific, but the below approach can still be applicable everywhere.

If you want your loop to end when the char is "=", then you can simply compare with if condition and break the loop:

```
int main () {
char c;
while(1) {
 c=getchar();
 if (c == '=') {
   break;
 }
 printf("print ");
 putchar(c);

 }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: The documentation of `scanf` that you are referencing is platform-specific. Not all of the information applies to ISO C. Therefore, you may want to refer to platform-neutral documentation instead. I recommend [this one](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: @AndreasWenzel, you are right.